# Initializing member variable without initializer list and a type that does not have a default constructor?

Tags: c++

I have to write a wrapper around the liblas reader class. I want to create the reader instance in the constructor and save it inside a member variable.

```
class LASPointReader : PointReader{
private: 
    liblas::Reader reader;

    ...
}
```

This is what I thought would work:

```
LASPointReader::LASPointReader(string file){
    ifstream ifs;
    ifs.open(file, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    liblas::ReaderFactory f;
    reader = f.CreateWithStream(ifs);
    ...
}
```

But this fails since liblas::reader does not have a default constructor. I then tried to make the reader variable a pointer and do

```
reader = &f.CreateWithStream(ifs);
```

Which fails because now i get "R6025 - pure virtual function call" errors at runtime when I use reader.

I then tried a rather ugly initializer list:

```
LASPointReader::LASPointReader(string file)
    : reader(liblas::ReaderFactory().CreateWithStream(ifstream(file, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary)))
{
```

But now, the reader only works partially. It could indeed load the header of the file but another method which is supposed to read the content fails.

How am I supposed to store this reader instance in my class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++ streams are non-copyable. Which means `CreateWithStream()` has no option but to take the stream by reference and store that reference. Which in turn means it will only be valid as long as the stream it refers to is valid. In your initialiser list case, that is only until the end of the initialisation. (And I guess you're using Visual Studio, otherwise the compiler would complain that it cannot bind an rvalue to a non-const reference).

If that's the case, you'll have to make sure the stream is valid as long as the reader is. This means making the stream a data member as well. In C++, members are always initialised in order of declaration in class, so do it like this:

```
class LASPointReader : PointReader{
private: 
    std::ifstream stream;
    liblas::Reader reader;

    ...
}


LASPointReader::LASPointReader(string file)
    : stream(file, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary)
    , reader(liblas::ReaderFactory().CreateWithStream(stream))
{
```